# PayPal Buy Now button using code supplied within PayPal account generates an error

Tags: html, paypal

I've tried and tried to get just a simple "Buy Now" button to work using the code generated from within the PayPal account:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="7DKPMH8DYQQSN">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Whatever I do this generates an error on clicking:

`PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.`

I have searched the PayPal Help system (such as it is !) and have found nothing but a rather dodgy reference to charset= but their description of how to set that within the account bears no relationship to what I see on my UK account !

I have reduced the page as a simple test down to just the one button on its own -

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML LANG="EN">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Membership Subscription</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="7DKPMH8DYQQSN">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

This still generates the error.

Have tried changing the charset to UTF-8 but that seems to make absolutely no difference - still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell there is a problem with that particular hosted button, and so you should log into the account at https://www.paypal.com , and create a new Pay Now button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons

(It doesn't seem like the hosted ID `7DKPMH8DYQQSN` *actually exists* ..??)

---

Within your PayPal account, the default language encoding can be set to UTF-8 in https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding -> "More options". However, this should not be relevant to the problem you are having, since your button does not have a dropdown/selection

Comment: Thank you so much ! Never occurred to me that Paypal’s button code might be nonsense ! I will follow your guidance and come back.

Comment: Brilliant ! You were perfectly correct but I'm not even going to try to figure out why Paypal were generating rubbish code ! Just so relieved to finally be able to get on and deliver. Many many many thanks !! Rod